# Ruby method chaining with an Enumerable class

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to adapt the method-chaining example cited in this posting ([Method chaining and lazy evaluation in Ruby](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/ruby-method-chaining/)) to work with an object that implements the `Enumerable` class ([Implement a custom Enumerable collection class in Ruby](http://rotati.com/blog/implement-a-custom-enumerable-collection-class-in-ruby) )

Coffee class:

```
class Coffee

  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :strength

  def initialize(name, strength)
    @name = name
    @strength = strength
  end

  def <=>(other_coffee)
    self.strength <=> other_coffee.strength
  end

  def to_s
    "<name: #{name}, strength: #{strength}>"
  end

end
```

Criteria class:

```
class Criteria

  def initialize(klass)
    @klass = klass
  end

  def criteria
    @criteria ||= {:conditions => {}}
  end

  # only show coffee w/ this strength
  def strength(strength)
    criteria[:strength] = strength
    self
  end

  # if there are multiple coffees, choose the first n=limit
  def limit(limit)
    criteria[:limit] = limit
    self
  end

  # allow collection enumeration
  def each(&block)
    @klass.collection.select { |c| c[:strength] == criteria[:strength] }.each(&block)
  end

end
```

CoffeeShop class:

```
class CoffeeShop

  include Enumerable

  def self.collection
    @collection=[]
    @collection << Coffee.new("Laos", 10)
    @collection << Coffee.new("Angkor", 7)
    @collection << Coffee.new("Nescafe", 1)
  end

  def self.limit(*args)
    Criteria.new(self).limit(*args)
  end

  def self.strength(*args)
    Criteria.new(self).strength(*args)
  end

end
```

When I run this code:

```
CoffeeShop.strength(10).each { |c| puts c.inspect }
```

I get an error:

`criteria.rb:32:in block in each': undefined method '[]' for  #<Coffee:0x007fd25c8ec520 @name="Laos", @strength=10>`

I'm certain that I haven't defined the `Criteria.each` method correctly, but I'm not sure how to correct it.  How do I correct this?

Moreover, the `each` method doesn't support the `limit` as currently written.  Is there a better way to filter the array such that it is easier to support both the `strength` and `limit`?

Other coding suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Coffee` class defines method accessors for `name` and `strength`. For a single `coffee` object, you can thus get the attributes with

```
coffee.name
# => "Laos"
coffee.strength
# => 10
```

In your `Criteria#each` method, you try to access the attributes using the subscript operator, i.e. `c[:strength]` (with `c` being an Instance of `Coffee` in this case). Now, on your Coffee class, you have not implemented the subscript accessor which resulting in the `NoMethodError` you see there.

You could thus either adapt your `Criteria#each` method as follows:

```
def each(&block)
  @klass.collection.select { |c| c.strength == criteria[:strength] }.each(&block)
end
```

or you could implement the subscript operators on your `Coffee` class:

```
class Coffee
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :strength

  # ...

  def [](key)
    public_send(key)
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    public_send(:"#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

Noe, as an addendum, you might want to extend your `each` method in any case. A common (and often implicitly expected) pattern is that methods like `each` return an Enumerator if no block was given. This allows patterns like `CoffeeShop.strength(10).each.group_by(&:strength)`.

You can implement this b a simple on-liner in your method:

```
def each(&block)
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
  @klass.collection.select { |c| c.strength == criteria[:strength] }.each(&block)
end
```

Comment: The `return enum_for` addition is not necessary – that case is already handled by `each`.